# update query returns -1 value eventhough the data is updated in database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

update query returns -1 value eventhough the data is updated in database . I am using sql server 2005 stored procedure with c#.
My stored procedure is as follows...

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_changepwd]
(
 @Cust_Id varchar(50),
 @Password varchar(50),
 @OldPassword varchar(50),
 @Username varchar(50)
)
as
Begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    Begin Tran
update
Customer_Utility_Reg_M_Tbl
set
    Password=Convert(varbinary(50),@Password)


where
Cust_Id=@Cust_Id and Password=@OldPassword and Username=@Username

IF @@ERROR = 0
    COMMIT TRAN
    ELSE
    ROLLBACK TRAN
    RETURN (@@ERROR)
    END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SET NOCOUNT OFF when you SET NOCOUNT ON it doesnt report the number of record affected